# Expected Initializer before '<' token

Tags: c++, stl, g++

I am working with following header definition.

finstrumentor.hpp

```
#ifndef _FINSTRUMENTOR_HPP_
#define _FINSTRUMENTOR_HPP_

#include "../../../api/probe_API.hpp"
#include <cstdint>

extern Instrumentor* INSTRUMENTOR_INSTANCE;

typedef void (*instrumentation_func)(uint16_t);

class Probe_Info {

  public :
    uint8_t* patch_addr;
    uint8_t size;
};

class Statistics {

  public:
    uint64_t addr;
    uint64_t count;

};

class Finstrumentor : public Instrumentor {

  protected :
    void (*prolog_func)(uint16_t);
    void (*epilog_func)(uint16_t);

  public :
    Finstrumentor(instrumentation_func prolog_func, instrumentation_func epilog_
    void initialize(Instrumentor* inst);
    virtual ~Finstrumentor();

};

/* Global Data */
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::list<Probe_Info*>*> probe_map;
extern probe_map probe_info;

typedef std::map<uint64_t, uint16_t> func_table;
extern func_table functions;

extern uint16_t func_id_counter;

Statistics* global_stats;


#endif /* _FINSTRUMENTOR_HPP_ */
```

When I include this file I get the following error during compilation.

```
In file included from ../src/instrumentor.cpp:4:
../src/finstrumentor.hpp: At global scope:
../src/finstrumentor.hpp:43: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../src/finstrumentor.hpp:44: error: ‘probe_map’ does not name a type
../src/finstrumentor.hpp:46: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../src/finstrumentor.hpp:47: error: ‘func_table’ does not name a type
../src/cyg_functions.cpp:16: error: ‘probe_map’ does not name a type
../src/cyg_functions.cpp:17: error: ‘func_table’ does not name a type
```

Comment: consider breaking this down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for instance: are you sure you included <unordered_map>, <list> and <map>?

Comment: Yes. I should have. Just found unordered_map is a missing include which fixed it. Thanks for the reminder :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the headers that define `list`, `map` and `unordered_map`.

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
```

Also, you shouldn't use [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `_FINSTRUMENTOR_HPP_`. You should (at least) remove the underscore from the beginning.